# how do i post back value of input?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, input

Using mvc I am trying to post a value back to the post function.

```
<input id="Order" name="NoToOrder" type="text" value="0" onchange=""/>
<button type="submit" name="command" value="Save">Order</button>
```

so In the controller what do I use as a parameter to get the value of the input?

```
 public ActionResult OrderManufacturedProductsPOST(int Order)
```

??

EDIT:
Iv checked view source

any idea?s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The parameter name should be the name of an `input` element.

Form's action should be also the action method's name.

Add name attribute:

```
<input id="Order" name="Order" type="text" value="0" />
```

Comment: Yeah I went to answer it as correct yday but it wouldnt allow me- some sort of timer said i had to wait 5 mins before answering...anywho